# Augmented Reality Concept in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to know how to implement augument reality concept in iphone. I have seen the apis like wikitude , Layers and Unifeye sdk but i am not that much clear about the concept. If any one know please suggest me which api have to follow to develop and if possible provide me some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Augmented Reality usually uses a space-filling-curve to reduce the 2 to 3-Dimensional problem to a 1-2 Dimensional problem. Basically it is just a reordering of sub-divisions of the surface thus it makes it easier to query the database for any locations or items in range or it helps partitioning the surface at all. You want to look for Nick's blog about spatial index quadtree and hilbert curve. A good example of a sfc is also the internet-map from the xbcd-comic.